# Configuring the GsonFactory of Google HTTP Client

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson, google-http-client

I'm trying to set a date format for the parsing of a JSON object coming from a Google HTTP Client Request. The line where I try to parse directly into objects `request.execute().parseAs(..)` does not work because of a date format issue. The objects come back with no values. The two lines below that one work just fine as I'm able to set a date format. Is there a way to set the date format on the GsonFactory somehow?

```
public class Main {
    static final HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();
    static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new GsonFactory();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        HttpRequestFactory requestFactory =
                HTTP_TRANSPORT.createRequestFactory(new HttpRequestInitializer() {
                    @Override
                    public void initialize(HttpRequest request) {
                        request.setParser(new JsonObjectParser(JSON_FACTORY));
                    }
                });

        SomeURL url = new SomeURL("");
        HttpRequest request = requestFactory.buildGetRequest(url);

        MatchBlock[] blocks = request.execute().parseAs(MatchBlock[].class);
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").create();
        MatchBlock[] blocks2 = gson.fromJson(request.execute().parseAsString(),MatchBlock[].class);
    }

}
```

The code was mostly pulled from here: [sample.](https://github.com/google/google-http-java-client/blob/master/samples/dailymotion-simple-cmdline-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/dailymotion/cmdline/simple/DailyMotionSample.java) I've tried both the JacksonFactory and the GsonFactory, including using the @JsonFormat annotation when using Jackson, none seem to work.

Should I just be parsing to a string then to JSON Objects instead of trying to do it using the parseAs? It seems less efficient.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately i'm not sure this can be done w/o a custom implementation of `JsonFactory`. the `GsonFactory` uses the `JsonParser` provided by gson, which is just a recursive decent implementation that doesn't do any custom transformation.

i'm in a similar situation and am just going to create a `Gson` object via the builder so i can customize accordingly.